# WordPress slow on localhost and Light-speed on 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, localhost

I'm working locally on a WordPress website on osx and having issues with loading time on localhost but on 127.0.0.1.

Any idea on the origin of that kind of problem ?

Comment: How slow, exactly, is "slow"?

Comment: Try with a clean wordpress installation without themes / plugins first.